# In Python is there any way to append behind?

Tags: python, matrix, append, behind

I have a matrix:

```
[[1 2 3],
[4 5 6], 
[7 8 9]]
```

and I need to create a new matrix:

```
[[7 4 1],
[8 5 2],
[9 6 3]]
```

I tried

```
new_matrix = [[1]]
new_matrix.append(matrix[1][0])
```

and got a new_matrix = `[4 1]` instead of a new_matrix = `[1 4]`

If you need more clarification, please just ask.

Comment: Appending is behind, prepending is adding to the front.

Comment: Is this a numpy array?

Comment: numpy arrays do not have an append method, so I'm assuming it isn't.

Comment: @cge,  python lists have commas between elements

Comment: While that's true, I've seen many cases where people don't put them in questions, especially if they're coming from other languages. It's not really clear, to be honest.

Comment: @cge, that is why I asked, if the OP is using numpy then they should stick to a numpy solution. zipping with zip will create a normal python list which would defeat the purpose of using numpy in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use `new_matrix.insert(0,matrix[1][0])`.

`insert(position,value)` allows you to insert objects into specified positions in a list. In this case, since you want to insert a number at the beginning, the position is zero.

Note, however, that this take O(n) time if new_matrix has n elements. If new_matrix has 100 elements, it will take ten times longer to add something to the beginning than if it has 10. That's much slower than adding something to the end of the list, which usually takes O(1): it should be fast regardless of how big new_matrix is. See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more on time complexity of python operations. If you'll regularly be adding elements to the beginning of lists, you might want to think about whether you can reverse what you're doing.

Also, note that the way you've done things, this will give you a new_matrix of [4,[1]]. I'm not quite sure what you want: if you want the final results as you are describing them, then you need `new_matrix = [1]`. If your code is correct (`new_matrix = [[1]]`), and you want `[[4,1]]`, then you'll need to do `new_matrix[0].insert(0,4)`. If you want `[[4],[1]]`, you'll need to do `new_matrix.insert(0,[4])`, and so on.

As an aside, since you seem to be doing things with matrices, have you considered using numpy?

---

(I'd like to point out that, if this answer seems a bit off-topic, it's because this question was edited to be something entirely different than was originally asked.)

As for the new question: while Stefan's answer is good python, you may be giving yourself too much work. It's clear you're trying to implement something like a matrix transpose, except mirrored. If you're doing those sorts of manipulations, [Numpy](http://numpy.org) is *much* easier and faster. In this case, with numpy arrays, you'd just need to do the following:

```
import numpy as np # import numpy
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) # Here's your matrix
new_matrix_1 = matrix[::-1,:] # Here's your matrix with all the rows reversed: [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]
new_matrix = new_matrix_1.T # Here's the transpose of that, which is what you want.
```

While this is just one thing, this will make *everything* you do easier. For example, arithmetic will actually work: `new_matrix+matrix`, `2*new_matrix`, and so on. You'd have to implement this manually otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively: new_matrix = [1] + matrix[1][0]

Answer (score 4):

Why build the matrix in tiny steps when you can just do it at once?

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> new_matrix = zip(*matrix[::-1])
>>> new_matrix
[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

Or if you do need the rows as lists:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> new_matrix = map(list, zip(*matrix[::-1]))
>>> new_matrix
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Explanation:

- First the `[::-1]` reverses the matrix, i.e., turns it upside down. That gets us a step closer to the desired result.
- The `zip` then transposes the matrix by combining its rows. First element of the zip result is the list of the first element of each row, i.e., first element of the zip is the first *column*. And so on, i.e., the zip gives you a list of the columns, i.e., the transposed matrix.

Comment: I think an explanation of why you reversed the matrix, and how zip can be used to transpose would be helpful here. Zip is powerful and has a plethora of uses, but I believe it is difficult to understand at first without a visual aid.

Comment: `reversed(matrix)` would be more efficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, it's not. I just tried it, `timeit` with a million runs. With `[::-1]` it took 5.39 seconds, with `reversed` it took 7.68 seconds.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, so you are telling me creating a whole new array is faster and more memory efficient?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It probably takes more memory, but yes, it is significantly faster in this use case, so saying it's less efficient is wrong.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, it does not probably take more memory it certainly takes more memory.

Answer (score 2):

From:

```
[[1 2 3],
[4 5 6], 
[7 8 9]]
```

to

```
[[7 4 1],
[8 5 2],
[9 6 3]]
```

can be done as

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
matrix[::-1].T
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're into list comprehensions and stuff:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = [ [ i[k] for i in matrix[::-1] ] for k in range(len(matrix)) ]
```